# Insert Linefeed into Word XML file

Tags: python, xml, ms-word

I am doing a search and replace in a Word XML file in Python, where I replace a string of text with a paragraph harvested from another file.  The paragraph being inserted has linefeeds, but the XML spec seems to convert linefeeds to spaces.  I want these linefeeds preserved in the XML document.  The linefeeds are represented by `\n` in my original text.  I have tried replacing that with `&#10;` type codes, which just appear in the word file as text.  I have also tried replacing `\n` with `</w:t><w:cr><w:t>` in an effort to insert the newline with XML tags.  That also just appears in the wordfile as text.  It also doesn't seem to be interpreted as tags when viewing the altered XML in XML Notepad:

[image: Screenshot of XML from XML Notepad]

How can I insert a linefeed into the XML that will actually be respected?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up getting this to work by adding the lines separately with the dom API:

```
for comment in comment_lines:
    new = dom.createElement('w:t')
    new.appendChild(dom.createTextNode(comment))
    parent.appendChild(new)
    parent.appendChild(dom.createElement('w:br'))
```